# Is a conjunction on duplicate premises valid?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

In propositional calculus, is it considered valid form to apply the conjunction transformation form on two identical propositions, such that

*1. p*

*∴ p ∧ p    Conjunction 1,1*

Comment: Yes, that's a valid deduction in propositional calculus. (There are calculi which don't allow it, but standard propositional calculus does.)